# Java version and R version is the same still getting onLoadNamespce Error

Tags: r, rjava

```
library(rJava)
```

Still getting same error:

> ```
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
>  .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
>   call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
>   error: unable to load shared object
> ```

Comment: I have JDK 9, JRE 8(both 64 bit) and R Studio(64 bit)

Comment: Which operating system are you using? The answer to this question varies by operating system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm facing the same issue as you when I have installed JDK 9. All packages that requied java that stops working.

Downgrade to JDK 8 it will work.